# What are the main market efficiency measures in the stock market?

Tags: equities, market-microstructure, testing, behavioral-finance, market-efficiency

I'm going to test for the effect of the change in market efficiency on the stock market portfolio, and, I want to know what are the main measures known in the academic literature in order to compare them and to choose the "best" one for a given market.

Till now, I found the following measures to test for market efficiency in the **broad market-specific** case:

- Variance Ratio (Lo & MacKinlay, 1988)
- Approximate Entropy (Pincus, 1991)
- The Hurst exponent (Peters, 1994)
- Mkt Delay (Pagano & Schwartz, 2002)

For the **firm-specific** case, I found that the event-study procedure is the most common to test the market efficiency.

Could you suggest other measures or other procedures to test for market efficiency in the *stock market*, in addition to the ones I cited above, or, alternatively, suggest which is the best one by providing a reference?

Answer (score 3):

There are different methodologies to detect a change in the market efficiency, both in the market and firm-specific cases.

In the **FIRM-SPECIFIC case**, the most common procedure is the event study methodology; you can find how to construct an event-study case explained in Kothari & Warner (2006), who collected all the event study methodology implemented till 2006 in the academic literature; below, you can find the paper reference and relative link:

> [Kothari, S. P., and Jerold B. Warner. "The econometrics of event studies."   > Available at SSRN 608601 (2004).](http://www.bu.edu/econ/files/2011/01/KothariWarner2.pdf)

In the **BROAD MARKET case**, there exist different measures/proxy for the market efficiency exploited in the academic literature to test and measure the effects of the change in market efficiency on the markets.

Below, you can find a list of the proxies developed in the academic literature to test/measure the level of market efficiency and the relative references in chronological order.

As regards the **review** about market efficiency test and measuring:

> [Bollerslev, Tim, and Robert J. Hodrick. Financial market efficiency tests. No. w4108. National bureau of economic research, 1992.](http://www.e-m-h.org/BoHo92.pdf)
>
> Lim, Kian‐Ping, and Robert Brooks. "The evolution of stock market
> efficiency over time: a survey of the empirical literature." Journal
> of Economic Surveys 25.1 (2011): 69-108.

As regards the market efficiency **test**:

- ARMA() Model test

> [Amihud, Yakov, and Haim Mendelson. "Trading mechanisms and stock returns: An empirical investigation." The Journal of Finance 42.3 (1987): 533-553.](http://www.business.unr.edu/faculty/liuc/files/RUC/topic_tradingmechanism/Amihud_Mendelson_1987.pdf)

- *Variance Ratio Test/MEC()*

> [Lo, Andrew W., and A. Craig MacKinlay. "Stock market prices do not follow > random walks: Evidence from a simple specification test." Review of financial > studies 1.1 (1988): 41-66.](http://www.econ.sdu.edu.cn/jrtzx/uploadfile/pdf/empiricalfinance/20.pdf)

- *Hurst Exponent Over-Time*

> Peters, Edgar E. Fractal market analysis: applying chaos theory to
> investment and economics. Vol. 24. John Wiley & Sons, 1994.
> Cajueiro, Daniel O., and Benjamin M. Tabak. "The Hurst exponent over
> time: testing the assertion that emerging markets are becoming more
> efficient." Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications
> 336.3 (2004): 521-537.

As regards the market efficiency **measures**:

- *Approximate Entropy*

> [Pincus, Steven M. "Approximate entropy as a measure of system complexity." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 88.6 (1991): 2297-2301.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.3060.pdf)

Look at [here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610929208830963) to know more about the statistical properties of the approximate entropy measure.

- *Efficiency Index*

> L. Kristoufek and M. Vosvrda. Measuring capital market efficiency:
> Global and local correlations structure. Physica A, 392:184–193, 2013.

- *Market Model $R^2$*

> [Bramante, Riccardo, Diego Zappa, and Giovanni Petrella. "On the interpretation and estimation of the market model R-square." Electronic Journal of Applied Statistical Analysis 6.1 (2013): 57-66.](http://siba-ese.unile.it/index.php/ejasa/article/viewFile/12385/11416)

**THIS ANSWER WILL BE UPDATED; ANY HINT, ADVISES OR IDEA WILL BE APPRECIATED**

Comment: Please update this answer for newer research